# How to match the whole string in RegEx?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm want to have two patterns:

```
1. "number/number number&chars"
2. "number_number"

1. "\d/\d \s"
2. "\d_\d"
```

These don't really work. For example the second one also matches "asdf894343_84939".
How do I force the pattern to match the WHOLE string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For second task(number_number) you can use **[^a-zA-Z]\d.*_\d.***, in you example asdf894343_84939, you get 894343_84939, or if you want to get only one digit - remove .* after \d.

In your first task, you also may use **\d.*/\d[^\s]**, for example, if you have 34/45 sss - you get 34/45. If you want to get result from whole string you must use in you pattern: ^your pattern$

Comment: ^\d.*\/\d.*$ also matches 3829/32a38. Why? Characters shouldn't be allowed. How do I force a whitespace after the second digit?

Comment: 1. ^\d*\/\d* \w.*$ 2. ^\d*_\d*$

Answer (score 9):

You need to use the start-of-line `^` and end-of-line `$` characters; for example, for your second pattern, use `^\d_\d$`.

Answer (score 2):

You colud use the '\A' and '\Z' flags -

```
Regex.IsMatch(subjectString, @"\A\d_\d\Z");
```

> \A    Matches the position before the first character in a string. Not
>   affected by the MultiLine setting
>
> \Z    Matches the position after the last character of a string. Not
>   affected by the MultiLine setting.

From - http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet